# SAS Raid Array A with Spare. If I remove bad drive will the Spare pick up?

Tags: raid, raid10

I re-posted below. My apologies, I accidentally uploaded a very old pic by accident..

[My server Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0jhG.png)

Comment: Second image clearly states you don't have any spares. Furthermore, I'd say you have two images of different setups.

Comment: Your images are from different systems. Please submit correct information.

Comment: I accidentally uploaded 1 wrong pic from my server.  My apologies.  My hard drive is not coming until middle of week. I am only trying to find a way to keep the server running at this point. I have done a ton of reading. I am unsure of this question at this point. ->  If I take the bad drive out today, would the server work until the new drive comes in. I dont even care about the raid at this point.  I just want the server to stay on.  I get a fatal error once the server reads the bad drive. Can i pull out one side of the mirror?  Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You have two LDs (logical drives, i.e. arrays). On the screenshot only one is highlighted. In the same time it's details are scrolled down. Both LDs are in degraded state, one is trying to rebuild, one is in the rebuild queue. In the same time it is not clear neither what exact type of failures these LD have, nor their raid level. Yes, you can pull one half of the mirror from the array, ***but only from healthy array, and this is clearly not your case***.

Comment: Attach `hpssacli show ctrl slot=N ld all detail` output from a text console, where N is your slot number.

Answer (score 0):

As clearly shown by your picture, you have **no** spare drive.

When the replacement drive will arrive, you had to remove the failed drive and start the rebuilding process.